# Copying files from Snapshot View

Tags: batch-file, cmd, clearcase

I am trying to copy files from snapshot view using the cmd code

```
cleartool find . -all -type f -version "lbtype(%LABEL%)" -exec "cmd /c echo f |    xcopy /f /y \"%%CLEARCASE_XPN%%\" \"%STAGING_FOLDER%\%LABEL%\%%CLEARCASE_PN%%\""
```

But while copying files I need to copy only after a certain folder from snapshot view like
`eg: DEV_VOB\LOG@@\main\DEV1_Integration\2\` I want to copy files only after this.

I did try `/EXCLUDE` in xcopy but not working.

Need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

The easier way is to include a `grep` before the `xcopy`:

```
 cleartool find ... | grep "DEV_VOB\LOG@@\main\DEV1_Integration\2\" && xcopy ...
```

If the `grep` succeeds, then the second part of the command after the `&&` will be executed.
If the `grep` fails, then the second part (`xcopy`) won't be executed.

You have various sources for a `grep` on windows, like [gnuwin32.sourceforge.net](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/grep.htm).

Comment: Can't we use findstr and then copy?

Comment: @VenkateshprasadVenkatesh Sure, you can try and use findstr

Answer (score 0):

Truthfully, this won't work. You're trying to use a version extended path in a snapshot view. Those will not work.

There is a command that allows you to extract arbitrary versions from the repository and place them in another arbitrary location: cleartool get

Something along these lines may work:

```
cleartool find ... -exec "cleartool get -to \"%STAGING_FOLDER%\%LABEL%\%%CLEARCASE_PN%%\" \"%CLEARCASE_XPN%\""
```

Comment: Hi Brian

While using the cleartool command got error
 cleartool: Error: Operation "file copy" failed: No such file or directory.
While i can c the file is still der in vob

Comment: Well, first start without the scripting, because my paths were guesses based on your path. I think you may need to fiddle with the names somewhat.